# How to fetch data from formula bar from Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

Is there any Java code which fetches data from the formula bar of an Excel sheet?

Comment: Rob is right. otherwise you have to parse the complex structure of excel.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly from Excel, as for as I know*

There is, however, an excellent library to interact with Excel from Java, [POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

For example, to read the formula from a cell, use this [method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellFormula%28%29):

```
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3"); 
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 
String formula = cell.getCellFormula();
```

*Maybe there is some Windows-COM object supporting it..

Comment: Thanks but i tried using poi still m stucked for getting formula bar values

Comment: It is giving me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a formula value from a text formula cell